# ASP.NET Core 3.1 API on AWS - Connection Timeout Expired intermittently

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core-webapi, amazon-rds

I have ASP.NET Core 3.1 API hosted in AWS (on IIS 10 and SQl Server on separate Box). More frequently than I would like, I am getting the below error (intermittently).

> Error : Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement. This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=21020; handshake=0;

Here is the conenction string:

```
"ConDB": "Server=SqlServerName;Database=Test;user id=User;password=xyz;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Application Name=AppName;TrustServerCertificate=true;"
```

If I add `connect timeout=240;`, I don't get the error but intermittently the connection to database takes a long time to establish before I see the API call results.

I have other .NET framework based projects on the same AWS setup, they all run fine.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you have intermittent network connectivity issues between the web server and the SQL Server. Does the connection string use `Server=SqlServerName;` as per the question, or `Server=SqlServerName\InstanceName;` instead? The latter requires reliable udp/1434 communications to the SQL Browser service on the target server so that the SQL Server Resolution Protocol can resolve the instance name to the instance's actual TCP listening port.

Comment: @AlwaysLeraning - its Server=SqlServerName;